# How to make the function compile into C faster, and how to determine which portion of the code occupies more memory?

Tags: compile, memory

If changing the value of 'n' from 2 to 3 in the above code increases the compilation time from one minute to ten minutes, is there a way to speed it up? Also, the code consumes too much memory during execution. How to determine which portion is consuming more memory? Or is there a simple way to reduce memory usage?

```
test[t_, x_, y_] := 
  Sin[2 \[Pi] x] Sin[
    2 \[Pi] y] (2 Cos[Sqrt[(2 \[Pi]/5)^2 + (2 \[Pi]/4)^2] t 10] + 
     Sin[Sqrt[(2 \[Pi]/5)^2 + (2 \[Pi]/4)^2] t 10]);
deltau[t_, x_, y_] = 
  0.01 D[D[test[t, x, y], t], t] - 1/25 D[D[test[t, x, y], x], x] - 
   1/16 D[D[test[t, x, y], y], y];
deltaT[t_, x_, y_] = D[test[t, x, y], t];
deltau = 
  With[{code = N[deltau[t, x, y]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
deltaT = 
  With[{code = N[deltaT[t, x, y]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
test = With[{code = N[test[t, x, y]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
dimension = 3;


n = 2.;


dn = (n)^dimension;(*和维数有关*)
dj = 400.;
(*dq=5.;*)
collocation = Tuples[Table[(i)/(n), {i, 0, n - 1}], dimension];
random1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random3 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random4 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random5 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];




psi[i_, t_, x_, y_] := 1.(*f[i,1,x]*f[i,2,y]*);
li[i_, t_, x_, 
   y_] := {(t - (collocation[[i]][[1]] + 1/(2 n)))/
    Abs[1/(2 n)], (x - (collocation[[i]][[2]] + 1/(2 n)))/
    Abs[1/(2 n)], (y - (collocation[[i]][[3]] + 1/(2 n)))/
    Abs[1/(2 n)]};
phi[i_, j_, t_, x_, y_] := 
  Tanh[{random1[[i, j]], random2[[i, j]], random3[[i, j]]} . 
     li[i, t, x, y] + random5[[i, j]]];
df[t_, x_, y_] := 
  Table[phi[i, j, t, x, y]*psi[i, t, x, y], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dj}] //
    Flatten;
ddt[t_, x_, y_] = D[D[df[t, x, y], t], t]; // Timing
ddx[t_, x_, y_] = D[D[df[t, x, y], x], x];
ddy[t_, x_, y_] = D[D[df[t, x, y], y], y];

dd3[t_, x_, y_] = 
  1/100 ddt[t, x, y] - 1/25 ddx[t, x, y] - 1/16 ddy[t, x, y];

xdim = IntegerPart[dn dj];

funComptotal = 
   With[{code = N[dd3[t, x, y]]}, 
    Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"]]; // AbsoluteTiming
funCompdf = 
   With[{code = N[df[t, x, y]]}, 
    Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"]]; // AbsoluteTiming
funCompDt = 
  With[{code = N[D[df[t, x, y], t]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
funCompDx = 
  With[{code = N[D[df[t, x, y], x]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
funCompDy = 
  With[{code = N[D[df[t, x, y], y]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
dq = 20;
dQ = dq + 1;
omegapoint = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[i/(n dq), {i, (j - 1) dq, j dq}], 
     Table[i/(n dq), {i, (k - 1) dq, k dq}], 
     Table[i/(n dq), {i, (p - 1) dq, p dq}]}], {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
    n}, {p, 1, n}];
omegapointbd5 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n, {z, 1}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}];(*向t-x投影0*)
(*omegapointbd1=Table[{collocation[[i]][[1]]+(q-1)/(n \
dq),0.},{i,1,dn},{q,1,dQ}];*)
omegapointbd6 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(k)/n, {z, 1}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}];(*向t-x投影1*)
(*omegapointbd2=Table[{collocation[[i]][[1]]+(q-1)/(n \
dq),1.},{i,1,dn},{q,1,dQ}];*)
omegapointbd3 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n, {z, 1}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k,
     n}];(*向t-y投影0*)

omegapointbd4 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(j)/n, {z, 1}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k,
     n}];(*向t-y投影1*)

omegapointbd1 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i - 1)/n, {z, 1}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k,
     n}];(*向x-y投影0*)
omegapointbd2 = 
  Table[Tuples[{Table[(i)/n, {z, 1}], 
     Table[(j - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}], 
     Table[(k - 1)/n + (z - 1)/(n dq), {z, dQ}]}], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k,
     n}];(*向x-y投影1*)



tabledfpoint = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {(n dQ)^3}];
tabledfpointbd1 = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
tabledfpointbd2 = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
tabledfpointbd3 = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
tabledfpointbd4 = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
tabledfpointbd5 = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
tabledfpointbd6 = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];


Do[tabledfpoint[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^3 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^3, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funComptotal @@@ omegapoint[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^3 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^3, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
    n}, {k, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[If[ k == 1, 
   tabledfpointbd1[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd5[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];
Do[If[ k == n, 
   tabledfpointbd2[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd6[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];



Do[If[ i == 1, 
   tabledfpointbd5[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd1[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];
(*Do[If[ i==n,tabledfpointbd4[[((i-1)n+(j-1))dQ+1;;((i-1)n+j) \
dQ,((i-1)n+(j-1)) dj+1;;((i-1)n+j) \
dj]]=(Join@@Join@@Table[funCompDt@@@omegapointbd3[[i,j]],{i,1,n},{j,1,\
n}])[[((i-1)n+(j-1))dQ+1;;((i-1)n+j) dQ,((i-1)n+(j-1)) \
dj+1;;((i-1)n+j) dj]]],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}];*)
Do[If[ i == 1, 
   tabledfpointbd6[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompDt @@@ omegapointbd1[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];

Do[If[ j == 1, 
   tabledfpointbd3[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd3[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];
Do[If[ j == n, 
   tabledfpointbd4[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]] = (Join @@ 
       Join @@ Join @@ 
         Table[funCompdf @@@ omegapointbd4[[i, j, k]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
           1, n}, {k, 1, 
           n}])[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
         k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dj]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
   n}, {k, 1, n}];


table0t = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
table1t = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
table0x = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
table1x = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
table0y = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];
table1y = Table[Table[0., {xdim}], {n^3 dQ^2}];


Do[If[i != 
    1, {table0t[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = -(funCompdf @@@ 
         omegapointbd1[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]], 
    table0t[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompdf @@@ 
        omegapointbd1[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]],
    table1t[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = -(funCompDt @@@ 
         omegapointbd1[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 2) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]], 
    table1t[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompDt @@@ 
        omegapointbd1[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]]}], {i, n}, {j, 
   n}, {k, n}];
Do[If[j != 
    1, {table0x[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k)) dj]] = -(funCompdf @@@ 
         omegapointbd3[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k)) dj]], 
    table0x[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompdf @@@ 
        omegapointbd3[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]],
    table1x[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k)) dj]] = -(funCompDx @@@ 
         omegapointbd3[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 2) n + (k)) dj]], 
    table1x[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompDx @@@ 
        omegapointbd3[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]]}], {i, n}, {j, 
   n}, {k, n}];
Do[If[k != 
    1, {table0y[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 2)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj]] = -(funCompdf @@@
          omegapointbd5[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 2)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj]], 
    table0y[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompdf @@@ 
        omegapointbd5[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]],
    table1y[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 2)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj]] = -(funCompDy @@@
          omegapointbd5[[i, j, 
          k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 2)) dj + 
          1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj]], 
    table1y[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + 
          k) dQ^2, ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
        1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]] = (funCompDy @@@ 
        omegapointbd5[[i, j, 
         k]])[[;; , ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dj + 
         1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k)) dj]]}], {i, n}, {j, 
   n}, {k, n}];


joinjoin = 
  Join[tabledfpoint, tabledfpointbd1, tabledfpointbd2, 
   tabledfpointbd5, tabledfpointbd6, tabledfpointbd3, tabledfpointbd4,
    table0t, table0x, table0y, table1t, table1x, table1y];
lambda = N[100/Replace[Max /@ Abs[joinjoin], 0. -> Infinity, {1}]];
joinjoin = lambda*joinjoin;
point = Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpoint]]];
pointbd1 = Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd1]]];
pointbd2 = Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd2]]];
pointbd3 = Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd3]]];
pointbd4 = Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd4]]];
pointbd5 = Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd5]]];
pointbd6 = Table[0., First[Dimensions[tabledfpointbd6]]];

t0t = Table[0., First[Dimensions[table0t]]];
t1t = Table[0., First[Dimensions[table1t]]];
t0x = Table[0., First[Dimensions[table0x]]];
t1x = Table[0., First[Dimensions[table1x]]];
t0y = Table[0., First[Dimensions[table0y]]];
t1y = Table[0., First[Dimensions[table1y]]];


Do[point[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^3 + 
      1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^3]] = 
   deltau @@@ omegapoint[[i, j, k]], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}];
Do[If[ k == 1, 
   pointbd1[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd5[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ k == n, 
   pointbd2[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd6[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ j == 1, 
   pointbd3[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd3[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ j == n, 
   pointbd4[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd4[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ i == 1, 
   pointbd5[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    test @@@ omegapointbd1[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
   n}];
Do[If[ i == 1, 
   pointbd6[[((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + (k - 1)) dQ^2 + 
       1 ;; ((i - 1) n^2 + (j - 1) n + k) dQ^2]] = 
    deltaT @@@ omegapointbd1[[i, j, k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1,
    n}];
f = Join[point, pointbd1, pointbd2, pointbd5, pointbd6, pointbd3, 
    pointbd4, t0t, t0x, t0y, t1t, t1x, t1y]*lambda;

ceshi = LeastSquares[joinjoin, f]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

If changing the value of 'n' from 2 to 3 in the above code increases the compilation time from one minute to ten minutes, is there a way to speed it up? Also, the code consumes too much memory during execution. How to determine which portion is consuming more memory? Or is there a simple way to reduce memory usage?

Comment: Please boil it down to a [minimal example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example), please.

Comment: Typically, calling ``CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint`` on the generated `CompiledFunction` object helps to figure out what the difficulties may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Compilation speed**

Do you mean to create the random numbers at compile time (which is what is happening) or at runtime? Embedding all this data leads indeed to bloated libraries. Since the programm code has to go onto the stack and because stack memory is precious, this is a very bad idea. So I suggest to refactor your code to either create the random numbers within the compiled function at compile runtime (if that's what you intend) or to submit the random arrays as argument to the compiled function; you create the random arrays in the *Mathematica* session, so that they will be allocated on the heap.

Moreover, there is some sense in unrolling loops constructs like `Table` at compile time, but this typically leads to a performance gain only if the `Table` are *very* short (like with fewer than one or two dozen entries)

Here is an example for the latter approach applied to your first function `funComptotal` . Note that I surround everything by a `Block` that scopes `x, y, z, t, c, r, n, i, j`, so that can do all the algebraic manipulations without using clumsy function arguments.

```
Block[{x, y, z, t, c, r, n, i, j},
  
  li = 2. n {
     (t - (Indexed[c, {i, 1}] + 1./(2 n))),
     (x - (Indexed[c, {i, 2}] + 1./(2 n))),
     (y - (Indexed[c, {i, 3}] + 1./(2 n)))
     };
  
  \[Phi]ij = 
   Tanh[{Indexed[r, {1, i, j}], Indexed[r, {2, i, j}], 
       Indexed[r, {3, i, j}]} . li + Indexed[r, {5 i, j}]];
  dfij = \[Phi]ij \[Phi]ij;
  ddtij = D[D[dfij, t], t];
  ddxij = D[D[dfij, x], x];
  ddyij = D[D[dfij, y], y];
  dd3ij = 1./100 ddtij - 1./25 ddxij - 1./16 ddyij;
  
  funComptotal = With[{
     dimension = dimension,
     dd3ij = dd3ij /. Indexed[A_, {i__}] :> Compile`GetElement[A, i]
     },
    Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {c, _Real, 
       2}, {r, _Real, 3}},
     Block[{n, dn, dj},
      n = N[Length[c]];
      dn = Dimensions[r][[2]];
      dj = Dimensions[r][[3]];
      
      Flatten[Table[dd3ij, {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dj}]]
      
      ],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
  ];
```

This compiles in half a second on my machine.

Afterwards, you can call the function like this for *any* `n`.

```
dimension = 3;
n = 3;
dn = n^dimension;
dj = 400;
collocation = Tuples[Table[i/n, {i, 0., n - 1}], dimension];
random = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, dn, dj}];
result1 = funComptotal[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, collocation, random];
```

**Memory usage**

For `n = 3` the array `tabledfpoint` is of size `{10800, 250047}` which is *gigantic*. It takes more than 20 Gigabytes to store it:

```
N@UnitConvert[Quantity[8 xdim (n dQ)^3, "Bytes"], "Gigabytes"]
```

> Quantity[21.6041, "Gigabytes"]

Make sure whether you really, really need it. There is probably a reformulation of the algorithm that does not have to store all the numbers. Typically, what you want in the end is just some sum or another reduction of all the numbers. That means that you do *not* have to have all of them in memory at the same time. Look for example at the code below; both approaches do basically the same; but the second one does not require any additional memory but just one register into which to add.

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
   Sin[x],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

cfSum = Compile[{{fantastillion, _Integer}},
   Block[{result},
    result = 0.;
    Do[result += Sin[RandomReal[{-1, 1}]];, {fantastillion}];
    
    result
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

fantastillion = 1000000000;

AbsoluteTiming[
 rand = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {fantastillion}];
 
 resultMemoryHungry = Sum[cf[x], {x, rand}];
 
 rand =.
 ]

resultMemoryFree = cfSum[fantastillion]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will carefully study the solutions you provided and redesign the structure of the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, the compilation speed has improved a lot. However, I noticed that I need to use “funComptotal[t, x, y, collocation, random]” many times, for example, when assigning values to “tabledfpoint”, which requires multiple uses of “funComptotal”. Each time I use “funComptotal[t, x, y, collocation, random]”, the speed is slower compared to the previous compilation method. Is there a better way to achieve a balance between the two?

Comment: Sigh. I am sorry. I would really like to help you, but it would take me all day to first figure out what you try to do there in the first place and then to optimize your code. Your main problem is that just require way too much memory. From what I have seen so far I would gues that you could do the same with just one percent of the memory that you use now. Try to compute what you really need and store it only as long as you need. Use only small auxiliarry arrays and reuse them by overwriting them when the old information is not needed anymore.

Comment: Moreover, you have many loop constructs in which you call compiled functions. Loops are weakness number 1 of _Mathematica_, but they are definitely the strength of the _C_ language. So try to put the loops into the compiled functions, too.

Comment: Moreover, you have many loop constructs in which you call compiled functions. But loops are weakness number 1 of _Mathematica_. So try to put the loops also into the compiled functions.

Comment: That's all I can say for now.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your response, and I apologize for wasting your time with my question. Currently, the memory issue is not significant because in another question I asked, I have already started using sparse matrices, and the density of the sparse matrix can be controlled at 0.1 or even lower. Finally, I will apply the least squares algorithm to the assembled large matrix (relatively sparse).

Comment: The "So try to put the loops into the compiled functions, too." is a good idea, I will try it, thank you very much!